# Cannot see my image because = CORB blocked cross-origin response

Tags: javascript, cross-origin-read-blocking

Hi i have a little problem, i use the GIPHY-api to get GIFS (obviously) and when i get the url of the Gifs i need, i put them into my img src element. But CORB seems blocking the url for some reason

when i console.log the data.data[0].url i get this url =
https://giphy.com/gifs/soulpancake-funny-kid-president-kidpresident-rgk1DxSugZDFu

here's the code :

```
function verwerkData(data) {
    gifContainer.innerHTML += `<img src="${data.data[0].url}" title="${data.data[0].title}"/>`;
}
```

The error =
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://giphy.com/gifs/soulpancake-funny-kid-president-kidpresident-rgk1DxSugZDFu with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Quentin mentioned it before, you have to find the image URL, not the page URL containing the image URL. You have two options. First, go by yourself, if it's not a dynamic web page, on the Giphy page, and search by yourself the image : [image].

Else, using XHR or a backend request, perform a regex on the response content to extract the image. For the example :

```js
const regex = /https:\/\/.*giphy.*\/media\/\w+\/giphy.gif\?cid=[a-f0-9]+&rid=giphy\.gif&ct=g/gi
```

Comment: Hello thanks for responding really appreciate it !

is this it ? https://giphy.com/gifs/hello-Cmr1OMJ2FN0B2

Comment: No, for the page you sent, you should have this image URL : ``https://media0.giphy.com/media/Cmr1OMJ2FN0B2/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611189b7f4a03596f8fa2c37d760bfad1a42bcfdb25&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g``

Comment: I found it thanks for everything man ! (merci beaucoup) 

The command  i had to use was : data.data[0].images.downsized.url;

Comment: Oh you were using an official API !  You should have to give more details about the data you were using in the code, like, the JSON structure.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, i'll take notes for the next time. Thanks man :D

Comment: Seriously, this helped me a lot. After strugglng for 4 hours, I now realized that I am inserting a page link instead of an image link in the image tag which I got from the json response. Once I have the given correct image URL instead of page URL , CORB error is resolved.  
So, now I understood that the error is trying to say us we are displaying html page instead of an image with the link I got from json response. 
Thank u so much for helping out..

Comment: Yeah, trying to display an HTML content inside an <img> tag might not work. :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The `src` attribute for an `<img>` has to contain the URL to an **image**

It doesn't make sense to put the URL to an HTML document there.

The error message essentially says "This is an HTML document, that can't be right, I'm blocking it".

Comment: @Donnygroezinger — Change the URL in the `src` attribute from one that points to an HTML document to one that points to an image!!

Comment: @Donnygroezinger — You've deleted the question but `https://link.us1.storjshare.io/s/juzoluevjtuemnhi7qp7um2dtxdq/demo-bucket/missions.jpg` is clearly an HTML document containing an image, a bunch of text, and a link to download the image. So the URL does not point to an image. It points to an HTML document.

Comment: @Donnygroezinger — Try using a service designed to host static files for websites and not a file sharing service.